# How to give start and end date in python-scapy script

Tags: python, scapy

I want to print data from `pcap` by giving start date and end date, i.e, i want `pcap` data only from *`15.01.2017`* to *`19.01.2017`* using python. How do it?

Comment: use crontab for start and kill script?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get u. I want data from 15.01.2017 to 19.01.2017

Answer (score 0):

How about using pkt.time to evaluate each packet in the .pcap:

```
for pkt in pcap:
time = pkt.time
if time > 1484481600 and time < 1484827200:  # Start and end date in Unix time
    pkt.show() # Or pkt.summary()
else: pass
```